# deploy Mirantis Kubernetes Engine in VirtualBox

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssh

I try to deploy Mirantis Kubernetes Engine in my VirtualBox (ubuntu).

I make a yaml file like this:

```
apiVersion: launchpad.mirantis.com/mke/v1.4
kind: mke
metadata:
  name: my-mke-cluster
spec:
  hosts:
  - ssh:
      address: 192.168.100.194
      user: kub
      port: 22
      keyPath: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    role: manager
  - ssh:
      address: 192.168.100.194
      user: kub
      port: 22
      keyPath: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    role: worker
  mke:
    version: 3.3.7
    installFlags:
      - --pod-cidr="10.0.0.0/16"
      - --admin-username=admin
      - --admin-password=admin
  mcr:
    version: 20.10.0
  cluster:
    prune: false
```

But I have issues to connect SSH error output is:

FATA failed on 2 hosts:

```
[ssh] 192.168.100.194:22: All attempts fail:
#1: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain


[ssh] 192.168.100.194:22: All attempts fail:
#1: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are facing is most likely connected with the SSH authorization.

As you can see in the following documentation:

> - Target machines must be configured for access via [SSH using keys](https://www.mirantis.com/kubernetes-lab/kubernetes-lab/how-to-generate-an-ssh-keypair/) instead of passwords, and for [passwordless use of sudo](https://www.mirantis.com/kubernetes-lab/kubernetes-lab/how-to-configure-passwordless-sudo-on-linux/) for the administrative account. This is the standard for AWS EC2 VMs.
>
> -- *[Mirantis.com: Download: Mirantis cloud native platform: Mirantis kubernetes engine](https://www.mirantis.com/download/mirantis-cloud-native-platform/mirantis-kubernetes-engine/)*

---

I've tried to replicate the same error and it occurred when the SSH key (public one) wasn't placed in the target machine (`/home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` depending on the setup):

```sh
INFO ==> Running phase: Open Remote Connection 
INFO See /SOME/PATH/.mirantis-launchpad/cluster/hello-cluster/apply.log for more logs  
FATA failed on 2 hosts:
 - [ssh] 192.168.0.123:22: All attempts fail:
#1: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
 - [ssh] 192.168.0.123:22: All attempts fail:
#1: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

To fix that you would need to configure the [password-less login](https://www.mirantis.com/kubernetes-lab/kubernetes-lab/how-to-generate-an-ssh-keypair/) to your target machine.

---

Progressing this provisioning process further should also show you the `duplicate hostname` error (assuming that the duplicated IP addresses are correct).

---

Additional resources:

- *[Mirantis.com: Software: Mirantis: Mirantis Kubernetes Engine](https://www.mirantis.com/software/mirantis-kubernetes-engine/)*